# Stop NSTimer running from application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> I have start a timer to call a method after 10 seconds. the timer start from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. it works fine but I want to stop that timer from another UISubclass at the time of logout. How I can do this my code is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{  
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self setupTimer];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
-(void)setupTimer;
{
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10 
                                    target:self
                                  selector:@selector(triggerTimer:)
                                  userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

-(void)triggerTimer:(NSTimer*)timer;
{
    NSLog(@"===============this method is call after every 10            second===========================");
    Getlocation *object=[[Getlocation alloc] init];
    [object updatelocation];
}
  -(void)stopTimer:(NSTimer*)timer;
 {
   [timer invalidate];
   timer=nil;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([timer isValid])
     [timer invalidate];

timer = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take an object of NSTimer.
Write this line where do you want to call method

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(NEWTIMER) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Write this code there do you want stop timer.

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
[timer release];
```

if you want stop timer when your app came background .you should write this code into this method.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [timer invalidate];
   timer = nil;
   [timer release];
}
```

Comment: :Thanks for your reply, but after logout my login view is appeared,this time i dont want to execute timer task, after log out.

Answer (score 0):

Write code in logout ButtonAction method.

> -(IBAction)LogOutButtonPressed:(id)sender {
>
> [timer invalidate];    timer = nil;    [timer release];
>
> }

Comment: but i created my timer in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions from here this timer is invoked if you see the code.